# Interactive training site for Javascript complete with code challenges

Tags: javascript, training

A few months ago I discovered a cool course called [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/). This is a great site that allows us to write code and see the results. It takes us through the paces to get us up to speed with Rails. You have to pass each level (including code challenges) before being taken to the next level, and it gets you grounded in the fundamentals of Rails.

I'm wondering if an interactive tutorial site exists for Javascript? One that will walk me through the paces of writing better Javascript, and challenge me along the way.

Comment: nice, really racking up the down votes here.

Comment: Hi Chase, while this might make a great blog post or discussion forum topic, creating lists of tutorial recommendations is [outside the scope of the Stack Exchange style of Q&A](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: hmm, not sure if I agree with you @MarkTrapp. I'm not asking an open-ended question. Nor am I looking for a list. This is a direct question that can have a simple and definitive answer. If I can do X with Language A, how can I do the same with Language B?

Comment: If you have specific questions about software development that aren't asking for a recommendation for a tutorial, feel free to ask those, instead: here if they're about conceptual and white-board issues in software development, or our sister site, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) if they're about a specific implementation you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following answer might not help you with general Javascript, but it might. And it'll definitely help with jQuery.

From the makers of Rails for Zombies, I present to you, [jQuery Air: Captain's Log](http://www.codeschool.com/courses/jquery-air-captains-log) and [jQuery Air: First Flight](http://www.codeschool.com/courses/jquery-air-first-flight).

Yes, I know. Its jQuery. But I guarantee you it will help at least a bit...

Comment: Yeah, that's really cool for sure.

Comment: It appears as though the answer simply is to use http://www.codeschool.com/. They seem to do a lot of this kind of stuff.